# Calculus: limits, factorisation and cancelling because $x \neq -3$

Tags: calculus, limits, factoring, limits-without-lhopital

Got the question from [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/video/fancy-algebra-to-find-a-limit-and-make-a-function-continuous) under the linked chapter.

[image: Screenshot of working and question in orange text]

Why is it that we need to establish that “$x$ is not equal $-3$” before we cancel after factoring?

I was under the impression we can cancel any algebra that we can simplify.

Comment: $g(x)$ is defined as a ratio for $x\ne-3$; for $x=-3$, that ratio is undefined (would involve division by zero), so $g(x)$ is defined with a different expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the act of canceling that requires us to establish/require that $x$ is not equal to $-3$, but the fact that $x+3$ appears as the denominator of a fraction. After canceling, we have to remember that the formula we get is valid only for $x \neq -3$, even though $x+3$ doesn't appear as a denominator anymore.

Comment: I see, yea it makes sense that we'd need to state that once we encounter the issue and tag it to the statement throughout. We then use the limit to solve what could not have been solved otherwise by getting infinitely close to the value -3. So cool!